# linking rails objects through foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to link rails objects through foreign keys?  Here is my example.  a Practitioner has a timecard (collect hours worked per day).  I want to put the practitioner's id on the appointment to show this:

from routes.rb

```
  resources :locations do
    resources :practitioners, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :practitioners, except: [:new, :create] do
    resources :timecards, except: :delete
    resources :appointments
  end
```

timecard.rb - you can see here I forced the timecard.practitioner_id to be 3, but that was a brute force testing effort.

```
class Timecard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :practitioner
 attr_protected :id

  before_save :set_practitioner_id

  def set_practitioner_id
    if self.practitioner_id.blank?
      self.practitioner_id = 3
    end
  end
end
```

And from my controller...

```
def create
    @practitioner = Practitioner.find(params[:practitioner_id])
    @timecard = Timecard.create(params[:timecard])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @timecard.save
        format.html { redirect_to @practitioner, notice: 'Timecard was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @timecard, status: :created, location: @timecard }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @timecard.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I can see the parameter for the practitioner_id = 3 (which is what I want to use), I just don't know how to access it in the code.

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"DIp4R31McXnBNP4NB06KDTzV+8lLcWvxbq1w9J+Z1+M=",
 "timecard"=>{
   "hours_worked"=>"2",
   "activity_date(1i)"=>"2013",
   "activity_date(2i)"=>"3",
   "activity_date(3i)"=>"20",
   "practitioner_id"=>"",
   "location_id"=>"1"
 },
 "commit"=>"Create Timecard",
 "practitioner_id"=>"3"   <== this is what I want to use
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that a practitioner has many timecards so you should be able to do something like

```
# practitioner.rb
has_many :timecards

# controller
@practitioner = Practitioner.find(params[:practitioner_id])
@timecard = @practitioner.timecards.build(params[:timecard])
```

having the association set up will take care of setting the foreign keys for you.

Comment: from that statement, it's not really clear whether it's a `has_one` or `has_many` association but the logical answer is `has_many` where a practitioner has a lot of timecards which are created per date.

Comment: has_many - I'm trying out both answers and not getting it... so I must be missing something else.

Comment: Turns out this did the trick... with the exception of not using the build method but the create method.  Wonder if that's a version issue.

'@practitioner = Practitioner.find(params[:practitioner_id])'
    '@timecard = @practitioner.timecard.create(params[:timecard])'

Comment: hmm. I used `build` because you're calling `save` later on.  When you call `create`, you don't need to call `save` later.

Comment: Now that you put it that way, build makes sense... except that ruby kept rejecting it as a valid method.

Comment: make sure that you're using the plural form `timecards`. not really sure why you're not getting errors when you call `create`. it should raise an error unless you have another association/method called timecard?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at it now and it definitely looks like just 'timecard'.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can simply set `@timecard.practitioner = @practitioner` before saving your timecard in the controller. You can do that because `belongs_to` [gives you](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) a `practioner=` method that "Assigns the associate object, extracts the primary key, and sets it as the foreign key."